# get values from factor using matrix

Tags: r

I want to extract some values from a factor, but instead of having one index string i have a data.matrix containing multiple columns, all containing indexes.

I have:

```
f<-factor(c('a','b','c','a'))
d<-data.matrix(data.frame(t=c(1,3,2),u=c(2,3,4)))
> f[d]
[1] a c b b c a
```

But instead of having all return values in one vector, I would like to maintain the data.matrix structure like this:

```
[,1][,2]
a   b
c   c
b   a
```

How is this possible i en elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of the definition of *elegant*, but you are essentially looking for `dim()`.

You can do this in a cryptic way with `dim<-()`, like this:

```
`dim<-`(f[d], dim(d))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] a    b   
## [2,] c    c   
## [3,] b    a   
## Levels: a b c
```

Less cryptic would be the following (though note the slight difference in the result).

```
matrix(f[d], ncol = ncol(d))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] "a"  "b" 
## [2,] "c"  "c" 
## [3,] "b"  "a"
```

---

If you're after a `data.frame`, then try:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(`dim<-`(f[d], dim(d)))
##   V1 V2
## 1  a  b
## 2  c  c
## 3  b  a
```

Or `data.frame(matrix(f[d], ncol = ncol(d)))`.

Comment: Thank for that incredible fast answer. Its much more elegant than what i had in mind (looping and adding one at the time;-) )

Comment: Is it possible you can add how to convert the multidimensional factor into a data.frame. I tried multiple solutions but end up with 1 vector all the time.

Comment: as.data.frame returns just data.frame containing multidimetional factor (6 obs. of 1 variable). And then i tried a loot that gave some funny results (I wont encumber you with showing you that;-) )

Comment: Found the solution: as.data.frame(matrix(res,dim(res))) does the trick

Comment: @JensHenrik, Glad to hear it. See my update for further alternatives.